# Is it possible to pass multiple blocks as subroutine parameters?

Tags: perl, parameter-passing, subroutine

Having in mind something like

```
my_sub { block1 }, { block2 }
```

it seems impossible with Perl, as only the first parameter can be passed as a block; further parameters are interpreted as hash references it seems.

Is it possible to pass multiple blocks to a user-defined Perl routine, and if not, what is the technical problem?

(I know that the above works when using `sub`s instead of blocks, but that is a bit ugly to write. Thus not considered to be a "solution")

Comment: Apologies that I didn't find that question. Anyway, I've improved tagging there and contributed my share.